# What is the complexity of global solution of a nonlinear system?

Tags: numerical-methods, computational-complexity, nonlinear-system

Consider an $n$-dimensional system $F_j(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = 0, j = 1, \ldots, n$. The functions $F_j$ can be considered as monotonic w.r.t. all $x_i$. What is the complexity of the problem of finding all roots of the system? Is it $O(2^n)$ or it may be enhanced as in a linear case?

Comment: What would be the method that has order $O(2^n)$? Does this method work independent of how complicated the functions are? How does the targeted error level influence the complexity?

Comment: @LutzLehmann I would propose a method that considers all 2D cross-sections $x_1x_2, x_2x_3, x_3x_1$ and chooses the first variable ($x_1, x_2, x_3$) from minimax criterion. It means that zero-level lines are calculated, they are decreasing, and the point $x_1^*$ is chosen such that $\max x_2(x_1) - \min x_2(x_1)$ is min. Then do the same for $x_3(x_2)$. If we have several local minimums, let us create a set of coordinates $\{x_1^*\}$, and for each coordinate we choose $k$-th local minimum at each step. So, the total number of threads will be the product of these sets powers, and it is $k^n$.

Comment: I'm going to test this minimax algorithm first for linear systems. If it works then maybe different cross-sections may be considered separately, and so the algorithm can be parallelized. For linear systems, every set $\{x_i^*\}$ consists of only 1 point, so the algorithm is polynomial.

Another approach is to use the least-squares method and globally solve the optimization problem, but it will be $2^n$ if running the algorithms from every corner of $n$-dimensional cube (trusted region).

@AlexK I'm not sure that 2D bisection works fine, and it is also exponential: $h^n$.

Comment: You're looking for accuracy relative to the input, not the output, right (eg to have the location of a root known within some $\delta$, rather than a root where $|F|<\epsilon$, right?

Comment: @AlexK Both variants are possible, I think.

Comment: I think the latter (bounds on $F$) may be impossible given a deterministic algorithm. If you're interested, I can write that up.

Comment: @LutzLehmann [Here](https://github.com/lapkin25/nonlinear-monot) is an algorithm for 3x3 nonlinear system with monotonic functions (under development). The idea is to consider 2x2 cross sections when fixing one of variables, then solve overdetermined system with 3 equations and 2 variables by choosing k-th point of intersection of pairs {F_i = 0} and {F_j = 0} in each of cross-sections xy, yz, zx where k = (k_xy, k_yz, k_zx) is a triple index. It was checked manually that the algorithm seems to be working. Illustrations are [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/q/42430/11531).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the worst case, $F_j=0$ for all $j$, and then there are at least $2^n$ roots.  Obviously any method to print all roots must take time at least equal to the number of roots, so this proves that the worst-case running time of any method must be at least $\Omega(2^n)$.  In other words, there is no hope for a method whose worst-case running time is better.

In general, even with some restrictions, you still shouldn't hope for anything better, as this is at least as hard as any NP-hard problem.  Monotonicity doesn't help.  For instance, vertex cover and other NP-hard problems can be represented as such a monotonic system of equations.